# ImageView bounds extend beyond image

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I have an `ImageView` defined as:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|top"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-80dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/prem_BACK"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/tester"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false" />
```

and I see this in Android Studio in the layout preview:

[image]

And notice the bounds of the `ImageView`. Is it possible to have the bounds be along the actual edges of the image I am displaying?

Comment: `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`

Comment: adding `android:adjustViewBound="true"` did not have any effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView"
android:src="@drawable/tester"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```

Adding the scaleType to centerCrop should fix it for you. You can change the centerCrop to any other suggestions according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the scaletype to fitCenter

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|top"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-80dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/prem_BACK"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/tester"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
     />
```

Comment: Changing the `scaleType` to `fitCenter` had no effect

Answer (score 0):

set android:adjustViewBounds="true"

It will set the bounds of the imageView to match the content

Answer (score -2):

I think, the image is too large and you re wraping it so the imageview layout will be larger than you wanted to. Crop the image seems like the only solution you can do. You can try to scale

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, an answer really needs to demonstrate the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.

Comment: I don't have enought reputation to comment.